# Why are some movies "recommended for all women and girls"

Tags: performance-entertainment

Some movies are labelled as "Recommended For All Women and Girls". For example, the ones listed here: https://www.nigunmusic.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Recommended+For+All+Women+and+Girls

What does this indicate about the content of these movies?

Would it be wrong for me to watch these movies and, if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is known as "Kol Isha", "a woman's voice." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzniut#Female_singing_voice

At face value, the Talmud indicates that a man listening to a women (who's not his wife) sing would be inappropriate.

There are a zillion opinions about the context in which it applies today, and whether it includes "canned" performances (i.e. not live ones).

If this was a live performance, they would say "for women only."

So the question now on their label is: are they saying "it is definitely kosher for a woman to watch this, but men ... your call." (And if you don't think it's an issue, fine, go for it.) Or are they saying that the women who made this do not consent to ever having a man watch it? (Can they do that?) Honestly I'd lean towards the former.